# Alexa INTERNAL_SERVICE_EXCEPTION [Error reading entity from input stream]

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am using the Alexa Skill Kit, but sometimes this error appears, I do not know why this happens, if I repeat exactly the same sentence that generated the error, the errors do not re-activate, this happens sometimes but frequently.

```
{
    "header": {
        "namespace": "System",
        "name": "Exception",
        "messageId": "d54f1559-f45e-47a8-b558-d391793c2030"
    },
    "payload": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVICE_EXCEPTION",
        "description": "Error reading entity from input stream."
    }
}
```

I don't know if there is my lambda or if is an error from the skill. I need to know what is the problem to fix it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you share some more info like where this error is occurring? is it in the test simulator ? what is the request generated?

Comment: I posted [Here](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/179099/there-was-an-issue-processing-your-input-internal.html) also, I think It could be that alexa confuse the intents, but how I see more specific logs?

Comment: this happens when I try to select the `PickCategoryIntent` or `AnswerNameIntent`, tha pick intent has choises but the answer name intent not

Comment: Can you share your interaction model?